# Datasource not found in IBM BPM. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: websphere, jndi, ibm-bpm

I tested the connection through websphere and it works but when I try to execute query from BPM it gives following error.
IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0

Comment: You need to provide more information what are you trying to do, possibly code fragment, and the exception stack trace. This is too little info for anybody to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, WebSphere won't update it's JNDI references until the services are restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You may connect to DataSource that doesn't exist or undefined in Websphere.